# Pattern matching: using placeholders

Tags: haskell

I wrote this code to make a function removing every character `c` in string `s`.

```
delete :: Char -> String -> String
delete c s =
    case s of
        ("") -> ""
        (c:t) -> delete c t 
        (a:t) -> a : delete c t
```

I understand that `c` is just a placeholder for any Char, not the actual `c` given as first arg.

Is there a way I can use the `c` argument provided in `delete c s` in the `case` construct ?

Comment: Character literals are written with single quotes, so look for the literal `'c'`. You could, for example, use pattern matching: `delete 'c' s = ...`

Comment: See my edit. I don't want to delete actual c's, but whatever char given.

Comment: In the LHS use a different name for pattern matching (say `a`). In the RHS of the pattern match use `if a == c then ...`